# Webrick development server requires restart (config.cache_classes = false)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

Using Rails 3.2.11

I am working on a development project and I realized a couple of days ago that I now need to restart my server every time I make a change in the controllers or models, in order for those changes to show.

The 10+ similar questions here on StackOverflow has not been helpful since I have verified:

1. `config.cache_classes = false` in development.rb
2. I DO run in development mode
3. I do not use rails 3.2.4

I do not use unicorn in development mode and I have removed all things related to unicorn (to trouble shoot) but it didn't help.

Since I can't really place when this started happening I am having serious problems trying to pin point what is disrupting the reload of all classes and models everytime I reload a page (just as I am used to). It is surely a setting, a gem or something I use but I can't really place what it could be.

So, what I need help with is: **How do I trouble shoot this problem? What should I be looking for in my code that might cause this?**

My `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11' gem 'json', '~> 1.7.7' gem 'pg'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production do   gem 'newrelic_rpm'   gem 'heroku_rails_deflate' gem 'exception_notification'        gem "SystemTimer", :require => "system_timer", :platforms => :ruby_18     gem 'rack-timeout'   gem 'heroku-api'   gem 'unicorn'      gem 'dalli'     gem 'memcachier'     end

group :development do      gem 'system_timer' # Must be loaded for assets:precompile, causes problem on Heroku though    gem 'yaml_db'    gem 'fastercsv'   end

gem 'feedback' gem 'jquery-rails' gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete' gem 'googleajax' gem 'friendly_id' gem 'acts_as_tree_rails3' gem 'will_paginate' gem 'sitemap_generator' gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails' gem 'facebox-rails' gem 'redcarpet' # Markup gem 'hirb' # Pretty command output

gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete' gem 'authlogic' gem 'nokogiri' gem 'formtastic' gem 'bcrypt-ruby' # Believe this has to do with admin stylesheets


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default. group :assets do   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'   gem 'compass'   gem 'compass-rails' end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan for the formatting fix on this article!

Comment: You can use guard and the plugin guard-rails to automatically restart your web server as you make changes to your code.  Can't see why that problem is occurring though...

Comment: Guard-rails didn't really work for me. I got the same problem with it, I don't know if I did it wrong or if the problem stated in this article causes it...

Comment: Would you paste in your development.rb file too?